# Can PHP make HTTP Get request to Java?

Tags: java, php, rest, soap, curl

I'm trying to make communication between PHP and Java.

Here's what I want to do.
PHP pass a parameter ID to a Java file.

The Java get the ID and run some script and return a, ARRAY to the PHP.

I have read out a lot such as PHP/Java Bridge, SOAP, RestCall ...

But I couldn't found out one which works. basically is I don't know how to configure.

I want to find some simple examples which I can understand. And I don't need to use PHP/Java Bridge.

Something easier would do.

Update.

***I had tried Curl call to the Java file, on the $result = curl_exec($curl) returns the entire CODE in the Java.***

***I even try Java Servlet, it also return only the entire CODE in the Java.***

***What I want is PHP make a GET request to the Java, Java will detect the GET request and obtain a parameter ID. Run some process and return an ARRAY back to the PHP.***

***I want it to be done in a HTTP request only.***

***But I couldn't figure out how it works. I even tried the HTTPComponent.***

***Please help out and show me simple example in the PHP and Java file.***

I even follow this servlet http://brajeshwar.com/2008/handling-http-get-requests-in-java-servlets/
 CGI http://www.javaworld.com/jw-01-1997/jw-01-cgiscripts.html?page=3
, and not only these. A lot examples. But none work.

Did I miss out anything? I will provide more details. I used XAMPP, every project and file will be in my htdocs.

All request will be something like this "http: // localhost/test/...."

Thank you.

---

Sorry that I didn't stated clearly enough.

The JAVA file is the normal JAVA file such as

```
public class HelloWorld {
String hw = "Hello World";

public void getHelloWorld() {

            System.out.println("abc");
}

    public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("abc");
    }

}
```

Thank you.

---

Update 2

Here's my next question.

Like those Curl, Rest, Cgi call.. Its actually called to the .Java file right?
And the result return is the Entire source code of the .Java.

This is because there's no compiler to compile the Java class right? 
I put the Java file in the xampp/htdocs, I compile it using Netbeans.

So when I call from PHP, there's no one to compile it? 
Correct me if I'm wrong?

So I should put the .Java file in a server such as Tomcat right? Or ways to compile it? 
I tried to put in the tomcat webapps, and connect to it through localhost:8080/test/test.java

It return me error 404.

How to access to .Java fil using Web Browser? 
Please help me.

Thank you.

SOLVED

Works Java with RESTFul. 
And I can get Curl call to Java.

Follow this [guide](http://javapostsforlearning.blogspot.com/2013/04/create-restful-web-servicesjax-rs-using.html)

Very clear for beginners in Java like me.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to read up on Spring MVC and create a REST full webservice.  Calling an executable java class might work to ofcourse, but I do believe that isn't common practice.

Here is an example of a possible controller class to call.

```
@Controller
public class TestController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/helloworld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String helloWorld(HttpServletRequest req)
            throws Exception {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

This is pretty advanced java though especially if you want to configure it all in Spring.  I can't explain all of this in detail in this little post.  However this site might enlighten you more http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try the exmple of Rest

```
<?php
$url = 'JAVA_PAGE_URL';
// Open a curl session for making the call 
$curl = curl_init($url);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the POST arguments to pass to the Sugar server 
$parameters = array('id'=>$id);
$json = json_encode($parameters);

$postArgs = 'method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=' . $json;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
// Make the REST call, returning the result 
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Close the connection 
curl_close($curl);
// Convert the result from JSON format to a PHP array 
$result = json_decode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried before this code. But how should the code in JAVA looks like? print $result give me nothing, and print $response give me the entire source code in JAVA. I wrote a simple JAVA which print Hello World only. I don't know how can JAVA capture the ID and return a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will give you some better ideas to use cURL() for RESTFul webservices  .

```
 $curl = curl_init();     
 $url = "http:";
 $fields = 8;
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 //To use https
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
 $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

u can manipulate the $curl_reponse in php.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew how to use curl. But how can curl call a  java file. I tried to put the location of the java file, eg. http://localhost/test/test.java, and print $curl_response. It print out the entire source code in the test.java. I want to send a parameter ID to the test.java, and test.java will process it and send back an Array. Thanks

Comment: Okies,, But you have mentioned about all kind off web services in your question,U didn mention that you are trying out in stand alone applications

Comment: Then you can try out with Java Bridge itself . its very simple to use between the simple applications, just create a jar of your class file  and load in java bridge folder ,[Reference](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php)

Comment: I tried but it don't works. I cant get it JavaBridge configure. I'm using XAMPP. Is there any way to make it works with XAMPP? or maybe ways other than Bridge?

Comment: What is the issue you faced in using XAMP server ?

Comment: I preferred to connect using HTTP call. Curl is a HTTP call right? How do Java detect or receive the the HTTP call? I don't know how to write the code in Java to receive the call. How it should looks like.

Comment: Try to implement webservices in any kind of and access it via http. [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giepu/index.html)